# Matrix of nodes column style inconsistency

Tags: tikz-pgf

For the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes, column 2/.style={red}]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This picture is created:

[image: TikZ matrix]

I also tried with:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes, column 2/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=gray,minimum width=8em}]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is shown below:

[image: TikZ matrix, 2]

It seems that some styles like `red` and `minimum width` are applied. Why are `rectangle`, `fill` and `draw` ignored?

How can I use them in `matrix of nodes`?

Comment: There is a size difference if `minimum width` is not applied and `circle` is applied instead of `rectangle`. I am therefore guessing that `rectangle` is also applied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `nodes` key inside the `column x/.style` key, otherwise the behaviour will be as if you passed the option to the whole matrix, not the individual nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes, column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw=black,fill=yellow,minimum width=8em}}]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: matrix of nodes with node options passed to a column]

Comment: This is counterintuitive to me. Why is then `red` applied as expected? And why isn't the whole matrix bordered by a black border?

Comment: @ipavlic: If you supply `red,draw` to the whole matrix, all cells' text will be red, but a border will only be drawn around the whole matrix, not the individual cells. The options you pass using `column 2/.style={red,draw}` make the affected cells behave as if they were in a matrix that was created with `red,draw` (red text, no cell border), but the matrix as a whole is not affected.

Comment: I would expect that at least the second column has a border with `column 2/.style={draw}`. Even if the nodes affected by `column <n>/.style` behave as though they were nodes of a matrix that had those styles, I would expect that they would be filled. I am still confused.

Comment: @ipavlic: You can think of the `column <n>/.style` as behaving like a `{scope}[options]` environment: Only some styles, like text colour or line thickness, will be passed to the nodes inside this scope. Others, such as `draw` or `fill`, need to be passed to each node explicitly, for example using `[every node/.style={fill=yellow}]` or the shorthand `[nodes={fill=yellow}]`. When you begin a matrix with some options, those options will apply to the *entire matrix node* (so `draw` will draw *one* rectangle around the *entire matrix*), but not the nodes *inside* the matrix: Those will...

Comment: ...be affected as if they were inside a *`scope`* with the same options, so there will not be a rectangle around them if the `draw` option is used. As to why there isn't a border around the whole column: The `column <n>` style works like a filter: For every cell it checks whether the cell is in the specified column, then it creates a `scope` with the specified options. It is not really aware of what a "column" is, so it cannot draw a border around the whole column.