# Some problems drawing linked lists with TikZ's matrix library

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

Some time ago I found the question [Draw an adjacency-list representation of a graph with tikz](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_frm/thread/392b6ee0b33fcab6/fe4faddbb2935b35?lnk=gst&q=Draw+an+adjacency#fe4faddbb2935b35) and wanted to solve it. I could but with some problems which still remain and [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-should-i-draw-a-singly-double-linked-list) remind me them.

My solution was:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth] 
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,% 
   column sep=0pt,% 
   row sep=1mm,% 
   nodes={draw, fill=gray!20,%
     minimum width=.5cm, outer sep=0pt,% 
     minimum height=.7cm, anchor=center}, 
   column 1/.style={minimum height=.8cm}]%
{ 
  \mbox{} &[2mm] 2 & \mbox{} &[2mm] 5 & / &[2mm] &   &[2mm] & \\ 
  \mbox{} & 1 & \mbox{} & 5 & \mbox{} & 3 & \mbox{} & 4 & / \\ 
  \mbox{} & 2 & \mbox{} & 5 & \mbox{} & 3 & / & & \\ 
}; 

\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{ 
 \path (M-\i-1) [late options={label=left:\i}]; 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-1)--(M-\i-2.west); 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-3.center)--(M-\i-4.west); 
} 

\draw[->] (M-2-5.center)--(M-2-6.west); 
\draw[->] (M-2-7.center)--(M-2-8.west); 
\draw[->] (M-3-5.center)--(M-3-6.west); 

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,% 
   column sep=0pt,% 
   row sep=1mm,% 
   nodes={draw, fill=gray!20,%
    minimum width=.5cm, outer sep=0pt,% 
    minimum height=.7cm, anchor=center}, 
   column 1/.style={minimum height=.8cm}]%
{ 
 |[label=left:1]| \mbox{} &[2mm] 2 &\mbox{}&[2mm] 5 & / &[2mm] &   &[2mm] & \\ 
 |[label=left:2]|\mbox{} & 1 & \mbox{} & 5 & \mbox{} & 3 & \mbox{} & 4 & / \\ 
 |[label=left:3]| \mbox{} & 2 & \mbox{} & 5 & \mbox{} & 3 & / & & \\ 
}; 

\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{ 
% \path (M-\i-1) [late options={label=left:\i}]; 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-1)--(M-\i-2.west); 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-3.center)--(M-\i-4.west); 
} 

\draw[*->] (M-2-5.center)--(M-2-6.west); 
\draw[*->] (M-2-7.center)--(M-2-8.west); 
\draw[*->] (M-3-5.center)--(M-3-6.west); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

with this results

[image]

Now some questions:

1- I used \mbox{} to distinguish 'empty nodes' from 'empty cells'. Do you know a better solution?

2- Although `column 1/.style` is declared boxes from 1st column show same heigth than other ones. Why?

3- Using `labels` within nodes (bottom example) changes `node` (or `cell`?) center. This problem can be avoided with `late options` (upper example). Do you know a better option?

4- Looking at first and secon column from upper example it seems that node's name is not equivalent to node.center. Do you know why?

5- I don't know if it's a rendering problem but it looks like adjacent cells have a thicker separation line. What must be column separation to draw border lines one over the other?

6- Solution for [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-should-i-draw-a-singly-double-linked-list) show starting point of `*->` arrows aligned with node center, but here its beahviour is like in [Modifying `*` and `o` style tikz arrows so that they are centered at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11871/1952). Coul you explain me why?

Comment: For 5, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18521/tikz-matrix-as-a-replacement-for-tabular .

Comment: For 1, you can use `nodes in empty cells` key.
For 2, perhaps because the font is already larger than `.8cm`, so that `minimum height` does not matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can use `{}` instead of `\mbox{}` to save yourself some typing when creating empty nodes. As ipavlic points out in his comment, you can also use the `nodes in empty cells` key. This means that you can't specify all the extra gaps between the columns in the first row, because that would create a lot of incorrect empty nodes. Rather, you have to specify the extra gaps in the row where they are first used.
2. You need to use `column 1/.style={nodes={minimum height=0.8cm}}` to change the node behaviour. If you don't use `nodes=...`, you are basically changing the options that apply to the matrix as a whole, not the nodes (see [Matrix of nodes column style inconsistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18352/matrix-of-nodes-column-style-inconsistency/18353#18353) for more on that).
3. It doesn't change the center, but rather the label is assigned the node name (`M-1-1`). You can prevent this by adding the option `every label/.append style={name={}}` to the matrix. (*see example at the end of the answer for a demonstration*)
4. That's the normal behaviour of specifying a node name without an anchor. Quote from the [pgfmanual, section 16.11](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf): "When you say `(x)--(1,1)`, the `--` path operation will not draw a line from the center of `x`, but from the border of `x`
   in the direction going towards `(1,1)`"
5. In order to make the lines overlap, the distance between the columns has to be `-\pgflinewidth`. See [TikZ matrix as a replacement for tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18521/tikz-matrix-as-a-replacement-for-tabular/18524#18524).
6. In [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-should-i-draw-a-singly-double-linked-list), the `*-` line starts at the horizontal position of `<node>.two` of the multipart node, which is not the center of the second node part, but actually shifted slightly to the left (replace `*->` with `--` to see where the line actually starts). In the case of the `*-` arrow style, that's a convenient thing. Since you don't use multipart nodes, but one node for each rectangle, you don't have that anchor, and will have to resort to using `shorten < = -2pt`.

Here's your code with the suggested changes:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,fit} 

\tikzset{circarrow/.style={
        *->,
        shorten <=-2pt
    }
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth] 
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,% 
   column sep=-\pgflinewidth,% 
   row sep=1mm,% 
   nodes in empty cells,
   nodes={draw, fill=gray!20,%
     minimum width=.5cm, outer sep=0pt,% 
     minimum height=.7cm, anchor=center}, 
   column 1/.style={nodes={minimum height=.8cm}}]%
{ 
  &[2mm] 2 & &[2mm] 5 & /  \\ 
 & 1 & & 5 & &[2mm] 3 & &[2mm] 4 & / \\ 
 & 2 & & 5 & & 3 & /\\ 
}; 

\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{ 
 \path (M-\i-1) [late options={label=left:\i}]; 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-1)--(M-\i-2.west); 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-3.center)--(M-\i-4.west); 
} 

\draw[->] (M-2-5.center)--(M-2-6.west); 
\draw[->] (M-2-7.center)--(M-2-8.west); 
\draw[->] (M-3-5.center)--(M-3-6.west); 

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,% 
   column sep=-\pgflinewidth,% 
   row sep=1mm,% 
   nodes in empty cells,
   nodes={draw, fill=gray!20,%
    minimum width=.5cm, outer sep=0pt,% 
    minimum height=.7cm, anchor=center}, 
   column 1/.style={nodes={minimum height=.8cm}},
   every label/.append style={name={}}]%
{ 
 |[label=left:1]| &[2mm] 2 & &[2mm] 5 & /  \\ 
 |[label=left:2]|& 1 & & 5 & &[2mm] 3 & &[2mm] 4 & / \\ 
 |[label=left:3]| & 2 & & 5 & & 3 & / & & \\ 
}; 

\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{ 
 %\path (M-\i-1) [late options={label=left:\i}]; 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-1)--(M-\i-2.west); 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-3.center)--(M-\i-4.west); 
} 

\draw[circarrow] (M-2-5.center)--(M-2-6.west); 
\draw[circarrow] (M-2-7.center)--(M-2-8.west); 
\draw[circarrow] (M-3-5.center)--(M-3-6.west); 

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Example of how `label` changes which node is named in the matrix (instead of expanding the node):

[image: labels in matrices]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit} 


\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,% 
   row sep=1mm,% 
   nodes={draw, fill=gray!20,%
    minimum width=.5cm, outer sep=0pt,% 
    minimum height=.7cm, anchor=center}
   ]%
{ 
 |[label=left:1]| &[2mm] 2\\
 |[label={[name=none]left:2}]|& 1\\
}; 

\foreach \i in {1,2}{ 
 \draw[->] (M-\i-1)--(M-\i-2.west);
 \node [fit=(M-\i-1),draw,red] {};
} 


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer solve all my questions. I didn't know about 1 and 2. It's strange to me not declaring the same number of cells in every row but for sure I'll use it. Just a question about 3. I thought label was added to node size but you say "label is assigned the node name (M-1-1)". Could you explain it to me?

Comment: I've added an example showing that the label is an independent node that (admittedly in an unexpected fashion) is assigned the name that should be assigned to the main node.