# How to create the following figures in TikZ - Part 2

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

This is the second part of Question [How to create the following figures in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145883/how-to-create-the-following-figures-in-tikz).

I'd like to create the following figure with TikZ.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning-plus}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
kreis/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=20pt},
every node/.style={align=center}]

\matrix(mat)[row sep=10pt, column sep=60pt] at (0,0) {
\node[kreis](k1) {}; &
\node[kreis](k2) {}; &
\node[kreis](k3) {}; &
\node[kreis](k4) {}; &
\node[kreis](k5) {}; &
\node[kreis](k6) {}; \\
};

 \draw[-latex] (k1) -- (k2);
 \draw[-latex] (k2) -- (k3);
 \draw[-latex] (k3) -- (k4);
 \draw[-latex] (k4) -- (k5);
 \draw[-latex] (k5) -- (k6);

\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k1.south) {Text 1};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k2.south) {Text 2};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k3.south) {Text 3};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k4.south) {Text 4};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k5.south) {Text 5};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k6.south) {Text 6};

\node (n1) [above=of k1] {};
\node (n2) [above=of k2] {};
\node (n3) [above=of k3] {};
\node (n4) [above=of k4] {};
\node (n5) [above=of k5] {};
\node (n6) [above=of k6] {};


 \draw[latex-latex] (n1) -- (n2) node[midway,above] {Text 7};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n2) -- (n3) node[midway,above] {Text 8};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n3) -- (n4) node[midway,above] {Text 9};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n4) -- (n5) node[midway,above] {Text 10};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n5) -- (n6) node[midway,above] {Text 11};

\node (m1) [above=of n1] {};
\node (m5) [above=of n5] {};
\node (m6) [above=of n6] {};


 \draw[latex-latex] (m1) -- (m5) node[midway,above] {Text 12};
 \draw[latex-latex] (m5) -- (m6) node[midway,above] {Text 13};

\node (k1) [above=of m1] {};
\node (k6) [above=of m6] {};

 \draw[latex-latex] (k1) -- (k6) node[midway,above] {Text 14};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Actually I have the following problems with it:

1. The arrows above the circles are to short, how can I adjust them?
2. The text above the arrows is not vertically centered, what can I do here?
3. How can I add vertical lines like in the picture above?

Another Question belongs to posting, how can I quickly generate and present a picture of my code?

Comment: About the last part of your qestion: You can use the `standalone` class to produce a PNG of the diagram. Just add the `png` class option and compile it with the `--shell-escape` compiler option. However, this needs an image tool installed which does the conversion in the background. See the `standalone` manual for the details.

Comment: If you're using Adobe Reader, you can use the snapshot tool to take a snapshot of the `standalone` output, and paste it here (by Ctrl+G and then Ctrl+V).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For (1)**, it's probably better to define `coordinate`s which do not occupy space, rather than `node`s which do occupy space. Loading the `calc` library will allow you to calculate the coordinate just `1cm` above the node `(k1)`:

```
\coordinate(n1)at($(k1)+(0,1cm)$);
```

**For (2)**, instead of `node[midway,above]{...}`, use `node[midway,anchor=base,yshift=1ex]{...}`. Or, you can group the nodes into one `scope` and set

```
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={anchor=base,yshift=1ex}]
 \draw[latex-latex] (n1) -- (n2) node[midway,] {Text 7};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n2) -- (n3) node[midway,] {Text 8};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n3) -- (n4) node[midway,] {Text 9};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n4) -- (n5) node[midway,] {Text 10};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n5) -- (n6) node[midway,] {Text 11};
\end{scope}
```

**For (3)**, load the `arrows` library, add

```
>=latex
```

to the `tikzpicture` options, and pass the option `|<->|` to `\draw` (instead of `latex-latex`):

```
\draw[|<->|] (n2) -- (n3) node[midway,above] {Text 8};
```

### Full code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows,calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
kreis/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=20pt},
every node/.style={align=center},
>=latex,
]

\matrix(mat)[row sep=10pt, column sep=60pt] at (0,0) {
\node[kreis](k1) {}; &
\node[kreis](k2) {}; &
\node[kreis](k3) {}; &
\node[kreis](k4) {}; &
\node[kreis](k5) {}; &
\node[kreis](k6) {}; \\    };

 \draw[->] (k1) -- (k2);
 \draw[->] (k2) -- (k3);
 \draw[->] (k3) -- (k4);
 \draw[->] (k4) -- (k5);
 \draw[->] (k5) -- (k6);

\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k1.south) {Text 1};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k2.south) {Text 2};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k3.south) {Text 3};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k4.south) {Text 4};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k5.south) {Text 5};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k6.south) {Text 6};

\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
\coordinate(n\i)at($(k\i)+(0,1cm)$);

\foreach \j in {1,5,6}
\coordinate(m\j)at($(n\j)+(0,1cm)$);

\foreach \k in {1,6}
\coordinate(k\k)at($(m\k)+(0,1cm)$);


\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={anchor=base,yshift=1ex}]
 \draw[|<->|] (n1) -- (n2) node[midway] {Text 7};
 \draw[|<->|] (n2) -- (n3) node[midway] {Text 8};
 \draw[|<->|] (n3) -- (n4) node[midway] {Text 9};
 \draw[|<->|] (n4) -- (n5) node[midway] {Text 10};
 \draw[|<->|] (n5) -- (n6) node[midway] {Text 11};

 \draw[|<->|] (m1) -- (m5) node[midway] {Text 12};
 \draw[|<->|] (m5) -- (m6) node[midway] {Text 13};

 \draw[|<->|] (k1) -- (k6) node[midway] {Text 14};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With such a regular structure (and once you know how to do it) I think it's easier to create `nodes` and `coordinates` with just one `matrix`. With `row #/.style` and `nodes in empty cells` options you can avoid some typing and mix `coordinates` and `kreis` nodes. Even text under `kreis` nodes can be included as `nodes' labels`. After that, just need to draw arrows between already created reference points.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    kreis/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=20pt},
    every node/.style={align=center},
    >=latex,
]

\matrix(mat)[row sep=7mm, column sep=10pt, matrix of nodes,
             nodes={coordinate},
             row 4/.style={nodes={kreis},
                 every label/.style={rectangle, draw=none, font=\small,
                         text width=2.5cm,align=center}}, 
             nodes in empty cells] 
{
  & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & \\[-2mm]    
|[label=below:Text 1]|&
|[label=below:Text 2]|&
|[label=below:Text 3]|&
|[label=below:Text 4]|&
|[label=below:Text 5]|&
|[label=below:Text 6]|\\
};

\foreach \i/\k [count=\j] in {2/Text 7, 3/Text 8, 4/Text 9,
                                    5/Text 10, 6/Text 11}
{
    \draw[->] (mat-4-\j)--(mat-4-\i);
    \draw[|<->|] (mat-3-\j)--(mat-3-\i) node[above,midway]{\k};
}

\draw[|<->|] (mat-2-1) -- (mat-2-5) node[above,midway] {Text 12};
\draw[|<->|] (mat-2-5) -- (mat-2-6) node[above,midway] {Text 13};

\draw[|<->|] (mat-1-1) -- (mat-1-6) node[above,midway] {Text 14};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:

There is a problem with `labels` and `nodes` in `TiKZ v2.10`. The `label node` takes `node` name. This bug has been already solved in `cvs` version, but a workaround for v2.10 is proposed in [Some problems drawing linked lists with TikZ's matrix library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24378/1952). It consists in using `name=none` in labels options. You can see how it works with:

```
\matrix(mat)[row sep=7mm, column sep=10pt, matrix of nodes,
             nodes={coordinate},
             row 4/.style={nodes={kreis},
                 every label/.style={rectangle, draw=none, font=\small,
                         text width=2.5cm,align=center}}, 
             nodes in empty cells] 
{
  & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & \\[-2mm]    
|[label=below:Text 1]|&
|[label=below:Text 2]|&
|[label=below:Text 3]|&
|[label={[name=none]below:Text 4}]|&
|[label={[name=none]below:Text 5}]|&
|[label={[name=none]below:Text 6}]|\\
};
```

[image]

**Edit:** now, with version `TikZ 3.0.1a` the ABOVE code gives expected result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code, I changed the content of my figures because it should not be not part of the question. I recognized that the arrows between the circles are not on the correct position, i couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @user2143654: The arrows between circles are wrong due a bug in TiKZ which has been solved in CVS version. Look at [Jake's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24378/1952) to better understand it. I've partially edited last row nodes to show how to solve it.