# how do I make tikz circular arrowheads concentric to the point they connect?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have a box-and-pointer diagram but it looks wrong, because the circular arrowheads are tangential to the point it connects, rather than concentric to that point.

[image]

How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\title{immutable list}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \tikzstyle{square} = [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=1cm, node distance=2cm, line width=1pt]
  \node[square] (1a) at (0,0)     {};
  \node[square] (1b) at (1cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (2a) at (3cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (2b) at (4cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (3a) at (6cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (3b) at (7cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (4a) at (9cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (4b) at (10cm,0)  {};

  \node (1) at (0,-2) {1};
  \node (2) at (3,-2) {2};
  \node (3) at (6,-2) {3};
  \node (4) at (9,-2) {4};

  \draw [*-latex] (1b.center) -- (2a);
  \draw [*-latex] (2b.center) -- (3a);
  \draw [*-latex] (3b.center) -- (4a);
  \draw (4b.north east) -- (4b.south west);

  \draw [*-latex] (1a.center) -- (1);
  \draw [*-latex] (2a.center) -- (2);
  \draw [*-latex] (3a.center) -- (3);
  \draw [*-latex] (4a.center) -- (4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just draw a small circle which will automatically be centred on the appropriate spot?

Comment: Do you mean to say the black circles are not centered within the square?

Comment: Correct, the black circles are not centered; instead, they are, like normal arrowheads, placed to be tangent to their endpoint.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24305/1952

Comment: The image in the question is no longer available. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the required effect is pretty easy using the "old-style" arrows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{dot}{dot}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{0pt}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{2pt}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\draw [dot-stealth, red]  (0,0) -- (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...But it is much easier with the `arrows.meta` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{dot}{dot}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{0pt}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{2pt}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}
\tikzset{Dot/.tip={Circle[length=4pt,sep=-2pt]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\draw [dot-stealth, red]  (0,0) -- (3,2);
\draw [Dot-Stealth, blue] (0,2) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, I like it, but writelatex.com doesn't provide `arrows.meta`. :-(

Comment: @JasonS `arrows.meta` is only required for the `Dot` and `Stealth` arrows. The old-style arrow definition is fine doesn't require this. I've updated the answer to make things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

If you draw circles at those points, they will centre on the point by default which may be easier than trying to adjust the arrow length:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    square/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=1cm, node distance=2cm, line width=1pt},
  ]
  \node[square] (1a) at (0,0)     {};
  \node[square] (1b) at (1cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (2a) at (3cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (2b) at (4cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (3a) at (6cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (3b) at (7cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (4a) at (9cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (4b) at (10cm,0)  {};

  \node (1) at (0,-2) {1};
  \node (2) at (3,-2) {2};
  \node (3) at (6,-2) {3};
  \node (4) at (9,-2) {4};

  \foreach \i / \j in {1b/2a,2b/3a,3b/4a,1a/1,2a/2,3a/3,4a/4}
  {
    \draw [-latex] (\i.center) -- (\j);
    \path [fill] (\i.center) circle (1.5pt);
  }

  \draw (4b.north east) -- (4b.south west);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: circles and arrows]

Alternatively, you could shorten the start point of the arrow by the radius of the circle. Roughly:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    square/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=1cm, node distance=2cm, line width=1pt},
  ]
  \node[square] (1a) at (0,0)     {};
  \node[square] (1b) at (1cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (2a) at (3cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (2b) at (4cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (3a) at (6cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (3b) at (7cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (4a) at (9cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (4b) at (10cm,0)  {};

  \node (1) at (0,-2) {1};
  \node (2) at (3,-2) {2};
  \node (3) at (6,-2) {3};
  \node (4) at (9,-2) {4};

  \foreach \i / \j in {1b/2a,2b/3a,3b/4a,1a/1,2a/2,3a/3,4a/4}
  {
    \draw [*-latex, shorten <=-2pt] (\i.center) -- (\j);
  }

  \draw (4b.north east) -- (4b.south west);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: shortened arrows]

But the adjustment would need to be tweaked to get this exactly right.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    square/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=1cm, node distance=2cm, line width=1pt},
  ]
  \node[square] (1a) at (0,0)     {};
  \node[square] (1b) at (1cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (2a) at (3cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (2b) at (4cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (3a) at (6cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (3b) at (7cm,0)   {};

  \node[square] (4a) at (9cm,0)   {};
  \node[square] (4b) at (10cm,0)  {};

  \node (1) at (0,-2) {1};
  \node (2) at (3,-2) {2};
  \node (3) at (6,-2) {3};
  \node (4) at (9,-2) {4};

  \foreach \i / \j in {1b/2a,2b/3a,3b/4a,1a/1,2a/2,3a/3,4a/4}
  {
    \draw [{Circle[length=4pt]}-latex, shorten <=-2pt] (\i.center) -- (\j);
  }

  \draw (4b.north east) -- (4b.south west);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will give you circles with radius of 2pt (diameter 4pt) which will be centred if you shorten the arrow by 2pt.

[image: adjusted circles]

Comment: I like that second suggestion. How do I choose the circle size in these arrowheads? I would like to adjust them anyway.

Comment: @JasonS I would look at `arrows.meta` in the TiKZ manual for the options. I don't know how to adjust them for the `arrows` library. (I've not yet figured out how the two relate to each other and started with `arrows.meta` have just learnt that one.) Hang on.

Comment: writelatex.com doesn't seem to support `arrows.meta`, just the plain `arrows` library.

Comment: @JasonS Hmmm. Maybe they are using an older version of TiKZ? That's a shame as 3.0.0 introduces a lot of useful features. I'm afraid my TiKZ manual doesn't cover the old `arrows` library as far as I can tell.

Comment: screw it, i'm designing my own arrowhead :-( https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse24.html

Comment: @JasonS ;) Try to find out which version of TiKZ you are using first, though. That information appears to be for 1.01 which is rather old. `\pgfversion` will tell you if you put it into your document.