# Command to specify the exact height of a node in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-matrix

I have a maybe really dumb question. I am using a matrix of nodes where I specify a 'minimum height' for all nodes globally (1.5 cm)

However, when I now want to set the node height of row 6 to a lower value (1cm), this is ignored.

As far as I know I have the following option for specifiyng the properties of a node:

- text width ==> width of the node
- minimum height ==> (minimum)height of the node

Using something like text height makes the content of the nodes shift ugly.
Isn't there some easy way to specify the exact height of the node and not just the minimum value?

Comment: please show us an example what you doing. the best in form of complete small document with your matrix which we can copy and test  and in it show you what  you should do. btw, properties particular row, for example row x, you can change wit `row x/,style = {...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem;

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=1mm, row sep=1mm,
    nodes={draw, minimum height=1.5cm, anchor=center},
    row 2/.style={
        nodes={minimum height=1cm}}
        ]
{ & & \\ & & \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: okay your seems to work, I don't know where is the problem then in my case. my code looks nearly th same

Comment: @SRel, really? how we can now this? please. be so kind and show us your code!

Comment: @zarko oh I see my mistake looking here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/some-problems-drawing-linked-lists-with-tikzs-matrix-library
I just said  row 2/.style={minimum height=1cm} instead of  
row 2/.style={nodes={minimum height=1cm}}