# Problems with a matrix of multipart nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

Just for fun I wanted to reproduce the memory of [Can't get split rectangle to shrink small enough in this TikZ picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29753/1952) using a matrix of nodes avoiding the use of `\foreach` loops to place nodes.

My intention was to use a matrix of `alu` nodes with `nodes in empty cells` option
(no need of typing each particular node) and a particular column of `controlcache` nodes.

After some tests I've found some problems which I don't know how to solve. You can look at the following code and results.

First test (right figure): If I use a matrix of `alu` nodes and overwrite some column with `controlcache` nodes (multipart nodes), filling colors disappear. I've test to follow advices in [Matrix of nodes column style inconsistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18352/matrix-of-nodes-column-style-inconsistency) but I could not find the solution.

Second test (left matrix): If the whole matrix is made with `controlcache` nodes, the filling colors keep its value and there is no problem overwriting them with `alu` nodes even with particular filling colors.

Could you explain this contradiction?

And a second problem with nodes alignment. If you look carefully, blue `alu` nodes in the left matrix are misaligned with `controlcache` nodes, while gray `controlcache` ones are misaligned in second matrix. The reason and solution (`0.5\pgflinewidth yshift`) are in [Andrew Stacey addendum to Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29753/cant-get-split-rectangle-to-shrink-small-enough-in-this-tikz-picture/29761#29761) to the original question.

May be a better solution would be to draw two matrices, one for `controlcache` and another one for `alu` but I would like to know to control particular multipart nodes within a matrix.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[rgb,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define colors
\definecolor{shade1}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}
\definecolor{shade2}{rgb}{0.75, 0.75, 0.75}
\definecolor{shade3}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{shade4}{rgb}{0.35, 0.35, 0.35}

% Load TikZ libraries
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Text settings
\newcommand{\figureTextSize}{\tiny}

% Figure element lengths
\newlength{\gpgpuElemSep}
\setlength{\gpgpuElemSep}{1mm}
\newlength{\gpgpuElemSize}
\setlength{\gpgpuElemSize}{8mm}

% TikZ styles
\newcommand{\arrowStyle}{stealth}
\newcommand{\bendAngle}{45}
\newcommand{\lineThickness}{semithick}
\tikzstyle{box} = [%
  draw,
  rectangle,
  \lineThickness,
]

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\figureTextSize
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style={%
      node distance=0.375\gpgpuElemSep,
    },
    component/.style={%
      box,
      minimum size=0.42\gpgpuElemSize,
      inner sep=0pt,
    },
    alu/.style={%
      component,
      fill=shade1,
      outer sep=0pt
    },
    controlcache/.style={%
      component,
      rectangle split,
      rectangle split parts=2,
      rectangle split part fill={shade2, shade3},
      rectangle split every empty part={},
      rectangle split empty part height=0.21\gpgpuElemSize-\pgflinewidth,
    },
    layoutalu/.style={%
    matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
    nodes=alu,
    column sep=\gpgpuElemSep,
    row sep=\gpgpuElemSep
},
layoutcc/.style={%
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes=controlcache,
    column sep=\gpgpuElemSep,
    row sep=\gpgpuElemSep
}
  ]

\matrix (alu) 
   [layoutcc, 
    column 3/.style={nodes={alu,yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth}},
    row 2 column 5/.style={nodes={alu,fill=blue!15}}]
{ & & & & & & & \\ 
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & &|[alu,fill=blue!15]| & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
};

\matrix[right = 1cm of alu.east] (alu2) 
  [layoutalu, 
   column 3/.style={nodes={controlcache,fill=red!30,yshift=.5\pgflinewidth}},
   column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle split part fill={red,blue},controlcache}}]
{ & & & & & & & \\ 
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem, the colours, is due to the fact that the `fill` option overrides the `rectangle split part fill` option, even when the latter is given last.  This is actually documented (S48.6, p452 of PGF2.10), but you have to notice that `rectangle split part fill` sets `rectangle split part use custom fill` and that it is this second key that is overriden by the `fill` option.

Actually, it's not that it is *overridden*.  Rather it is that the paths for the components are drawn first and then the outer frame path is drawn after - it probably looks nicer that way - so if the outer frame path is filled then it goes on top of the paths for the components.  You can try:

```
\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split empty part height=.25cm, rectangle split part fill={red,blue},fill=orange,opacity=.5] {};
```

to verify this.

So you need to put `fill=none` in appropriate places.  Simplest is to put it directly in the `controlcache` style.  Since `alu` is a normal rectangle, specifying the `fill` option for that simply replaces the earlier `fill` option and that's why the behaviour is different for the second case.

The second problem is perhaps more subtle, and it took a while to figure out; though having figured it out then I see that it too is in the documentation (S38.1, p375 in PGF2.10).  It's to do with the alignment of the nodes.  Using the `matrix of nodes` key sets the anchors to `base`.  You can test this with the following by commenting out the `matrix of nodes` key (remember to load the `matrix` library):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes]
{
\node {a}; & \node{very}; & \node{long}; & \node{word}; & \node{with}; & \node{syzygies}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The reason that this is an issue is because of where the `rectangle split` puts its `base` anchor if there is no text.  The ordinary rectangle puts it at the same place as the centre.  The `rectangle split` puts it at the inner edge of the upper box.  This is half a line width higher than the centre anchor.  So to remove this behaviour, we need to reset the anchor to `center` with an appropriate `nodes={anchor=center}` in the `layoutalu` and `layoutcc` styles.

Putting those together, we get:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29891/86}
\usepackage[rgb,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define colors
\definecolor{shade1}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}
\definecolor{shade2}{rgb}{0.75, 0.75, 0.75}
\definecolor{shade3}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{shade4}{rgb}{0.35, 0.35, 0.35}

% Load TikZ libraries
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Text settings
\newcommand{\figureTextSize}{\tiny}

% Figure element lengths
\newlength{\gpgpuElemSep}
\setlength{\gpgpuElemSep}{1mm}
\newlength{\gpgpuElemSize}
\setlength{\gpgpuElemSize}{8mm}

% TikZ styles
\newcommand{\arrowStyle}{stealth}
\newcommand{\bendAngle}{45}
\newcommand{\lineThickness}{semithick}
\tikzstyle{box} = [%
  draw,
  rectangle,
  \lineThickness,
]

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\figureTextSize
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style={%
      node distance=0.375\gpgpuElemSep,
    },
    component/.style={%
      box,
      minimum size=0.42\gpgpuElemSize,
      inner sep=0pt,
    },
    alu/.style={%
      component,
      fill=shade1,
      outer sep=0pt
    },
    controlcache/.style={%
      component,
      fill=none,
      rectangle split,
      rectangle split parts=2,
      rectangle split part fill={shade2, shade3},
      rectangle split every empty part={},
      rectangle split empty part height=0.21\gpgpuElemSize-\pgflinewidth,
    },
    layoutalu/.style={%
    matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={anchor=center},
    nodes=alu,
    column sep=\gpgpuElemSep,
    row sep=\gpgpuElemSep
},
layoutcc/.style={%
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={anchor=center},
    nodes=controlcache,
    column sep=\gpgpuElemSep,
    row sep=\gpgpuElemSep
}
  ]

\matrix (alu) 
   [layoutcc, 
    column 3/.style={nodes={alu}},
    row 2 column 5/.style={nodes={alu,fill=blue!15}}]
{ & & & & & & & \\ 
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & &|[alu,fill=blue!15]| & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
};

\matrix[right = 1cm of alu.east] (alu2) 
  [layoutalu, 
   column 3/.style={nodes={controlcache,fill=red!30}},
   column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle split part fill={red,blue},controlcache}}]
{ & & & & & & & \\ 
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

With result:

[image: Multipart rectangles in a matrix]

which, due to the size, does not look a lot different (apart from the colours)!  But I can assure you that there is a difference.

Incidentally, my references to the documentation are not intended as "You should have read the manual better".  I only found them *after* investigation, and I consider neither to be obvious.  In particular, I only figured out the second after drawing lots and lots of test pictures.

Lastly, your pictures are great for showing that optical illusion where little grey circles appear in between the rectangles.

Comment: Thank you. Once you know where to look, it's easier to find the solution. ASAP I will apply your improvements to write another answer to gablin's question.